# Aurelia - Custom element inside repeat.for is not created after collection changes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

In Aurelia, I've setup a list of template objects and allow a user to add new templates using a button.
Each template has a detail view that consists of a custom element.

```
<div class="middle-box">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" click.delegate="addMailTemplate()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Add Email</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" click.delegate="addNotificationTemplate()"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Add Notification</a>
</div>
<div class="row p-sm">
    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTabs">
            <li class="${template.IsActive ? 'active' : ''}" repeat.for="template of templates">
                <a data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-${template.Id}" aria-expanded="${template.IsActive ? 'true' : 'false'}"> ${template.Key}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 no-padding">
        <div class="tab-content dad-templates-tabpane">
            <div id="tab-${template.Id}" class="tab-pane" repeat.for="template of templates">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <email-template-editor template.bind="template" if.bind="template.TemplateType == 'email'"></email-template-editor>
                        <notification-template-editor template.bind="template" if.bind="template.TemplateType == 'notification'"></notification-template-editor>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that when I create a new template (I add the new template to the templates collection) it correctly adds the new item to the list of templates but it doesn't create a new custom email-template-editor element.

[image: As you can see, the template-editor is not being rendered]

On the initial load, it does load all the templates as you can see here:

[image]

So this must have something to do with the binding of the repeat.for?

Here's the viewmodel js for the emailtemplateeditor.js

```
export class EmailTemplateEditor {
    activate(model) {
        this.template = model;
    }
}
```

And here's the html for the emailtemplateeditor.html

```
<template bindable="template">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
                <label for="key" class="control-label label-lg">Identification Key: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="key" value.bind="template.Key" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter the unique key" maxlength="100" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="label-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x label-lg" title="This is the parameter you pass into the WEBNOTIFICATION('Identification key') or EMAIL('Identification key') function."></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
                <label for="to" class="control-label label-lg">To: </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="to" value.bind="template.To" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="To: Enter recipients" />        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
            <label for="subject" class="control-label label-lg">Subject: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="subject" value.bind="template.Subject" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E-mail subject" />        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="key" class="control-label label-lg">Body: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea value.bind="template.Body" rows="20" class="form-control template-mail-body"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's the code for the add methods and the data loading intially:

```
activate() {
    var id = $("#data-analysis-definition-id").val();
    var sortByCreatedAt = function(a, b) {
        return (a.CreatedAt < b.CreatedAt) ? -1 : ((a.CreatedAt > b.CreatedAt) ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return Promise.all([
        this.dataAnalysisDefinitionService.get(id).then(data => {
            this.dad = data;
        }),
        this.dataAnalysisDefinitionService.getEmailTemplates(id).then(data => {
            data.forEach(function(obj) { obj.TemplateType = "email"; });
            this.templates = this.templates.concat(data);
            this.templates.sort(sortByCreatedAt);
        }),
        this.dataAnalysisDefinitionService.getNotificationTemplates(id).then(data => {
            data.forEach(function(obj) { obj.TemplateType = "notification"; });
            this.templates = this.templates.concat(data);
            this.templates.sort(sortByCreatedAt);
        })
    ]);
}

addMailTemplate() {
    var self = this;
    this.dataAnalysisDefinitionService.createEmailTemplate(this.dad.Id).then(function (newTemplate) {
        self.templates.push(newTemplate);
    });
}

addNotificationTemplate() {
    var self = this;
    this.dataAnalysisDefinitionService.createNotificationTemplate(this.dad.Id).then(function (newTemplate) {
        self.templates.push(newTemplate);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you using firefox? it is not friendly to using repeat.for along with using a loop variable on the same element

Comment: No I'm using chrome, haven't even tried it with firefox yet :-)

Comment: Could you add the code of the `email-template-editor` view and viewmodel?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne I've added these as requested

Comment: Well, the `activate` method works on routing modules, and you're already binding in the HTML, so the `activate` method is redundant here. Can you try removing it?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne just did, but the result remains the same.

Comment: Could the "template" variable name be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine, from what you've shared here. Is it possible you can inspect your DOM using the Aurelia Inspector for Google Chrome and see if all the properties are correctly bound to the newly added element?

You need an `Id`:

```
id="tab-${template.Id}"
```

and a `TemplateType`:

```
if.bind="template.TemplateType == 'email'"
```

Comment: I wasn't setting the templatetype on the newly created template objects! Bounty is coming your way once the bounty grant delay is over.

Answer (score -1):

The code is correct and should work. Probably your newly created template doesn't have the right `TemplateType`. Ensure that it has either `email` or `notification` and things should be ok.